# Segmentation Fault when trying to merge two sorted arrays

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and started learning more about merging two sorted arrays, but when I try to implement the code, I keep getting segmentation fault. I'm not really sure where my code went wrong and I was wondering if someone could look through it?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Array {
    int A[10];  
    int size; 
    int length; 
}; 

struct Array* merge(struct Array *arr1, struct Array *arr2) {
    int i, j, k; 
    i=j=k=0; 

    struct Array *arr3 = (struct Array*)malloc(sizeof(struct Array)); 
    
    while (i < arr1->length && j < arr2->length) {
        if (arr1->A[i] > arr2->A[j]) {
            arr3->A[k] = arr2->A[j];
            k++, j++; 
        } 

        if (arr1->A[i] < arr2->A[j]) {
            arr3->A[k] = arr1->A[i]; 
            k++, i++; 
        }
    }

    for (; i < arr1->length; i++) {
        arr3->A[k++] = arr1->A[i]; 
    }

    for (; j < arr2->length; j++) {
        arr3->A[k++] = arr2->A[j];
    } 
    arr3->size = 10; 
    arr3->length = arr1->length + arr2->length; 

    return arr3; 
}

void Display(struct Array arr) {
    int i; 
    
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr.A[i]); 
    }
}

int main() { 
    struct Array arr1 = {{2, 9, 21, 28, 35}, 10, 5}; 
    struct Array arr2 = {{2,3,16,18,28}, 10, 5};

    struct Array *arr3; 
    arr3 = merge(&arr1, &arr2);
    Display(*arr3); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You are missing the case where `arr1->A[i] == arr2->A[j])`, and it should actually lead to infinite loop on the very first element.

Comment: Also, not including `stdio.h` may make your program to use an implicit declaration of `printf` which will make it have undefined behavior.

Comment: You should probably check that `arr1->length + arr2->length <= 10` before starting the merge. Or better yet, redesign the `struct` so that you can allocate the correct amount of memory for the merged array.

Comment: @EugeneSh could you clarify where in the code I would implement this? Sorry, I'm not getting the logic

Comment: You have two checks, for `arr1->A[i] < arr2->A[j]` and for `arr1->A[i] > arr2->A[j]`. But there is a case where neither is true, so your indices won't progress and the `while` loop will get stuck. So add this check, or better yet replace one of the above with `<=` or `>=`. Or simply turn the second `if` into `else`.

Comment: Not clear why would it cause SEGFAULT though, still.

Comment: It seems that you did not give a proper size to arr3 in function merge?

Answer (score 2):

I don't get a segmentation fault, and I don't see why you would except from `malloc` failing from running out of memory. In that situation, a seg fault isn't really a bad thing, but a proper error message would be better.

However, it does produce an infinite loop because you don't handle the case where `arr1->A[i] == arr2->A[j]`. This can be fixed by replacing `if (arr1->A[i] < arr2->A[j])` with `else`.

You also have a memory leak because of a missing `free(arr3)`.

Note that `int A[10]` should be `int *A` so you can accommodate arrays of any size.

Note that I would write `Display` to take a pointer, allowing you to write `Display(arr3)` instead of `Display(*arr3)`. That would be a tiny bit faster, but the real reason is because you'd normally already have a pointer, so it's simpler/cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need size in your code as your array has fixed length
2. Use flexible array members
3. Use the correct type for sizes (`size_t`)
4. Do not cast result of `malloc`. If your code is not compiling it means: you use C++ compiler to compile C code.
5. Your sorted arrays can have elements in a different order. You need to let know your `merge` function what elements order arrays use.

```
typedef struct 
{
    size_t size;
    int data[];
}Array_t; 

Array_t *merge(const Array_t *a1, const Array_t *a2, const int order)
{
    size_t a1index = 0, a2index = 0;
    Array_t *result = (a1 && a2) ? malloc(sizeof(*result) + (a2 -> size + a1 -> size) * sizeof(result -> data[0])) : NULL;

    if(result)
    {
        result -> size = a1 -> size + a2 -> size;
        for(size_t index = 0; index < result -> size; index++)
        {
            if(a1index >= a1 -> size) result -> data[index] = a2 -> data[a2index++];
            else if(a2index >= a2 -> size) result -> data[index] = a1 -> data[a1index++];
            else
            {
                int comp = order ? a1 -> data[a1index] > a2 -> data[a2index] : a1 -> data[a1index] < a2 -> data[a2index];
                if(comp) result -> data[index] = a1 -> data[a1index++];
                else result -> data[index] = a2 -> data[a2index++];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

#define ASIZE 4
#define BSIZE 6

int main(void)
{
    //check for errors in real code -  I am too lazy
    Array_t *a = malloc(sizeof(*a) + ASIZE * sizeof(a -> data[0]));
    a -> size = ASIZE;
    Array_t *b = malloc(sizeof(*b) + BSIZE * sizeof(b -> data[0]));
    b -> size = BSIZE;

    Array_t *c;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < a -> size; i++ ) a -> data[i] = i;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < b -> size; i++ ) b -> data[i] = i;

    c = merge(a,b,0);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < c -> size; i++ ) printf("[%zu] %d\n", i, c -> data[i]);

    free(c);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < a -> size; i++ ) a -> data[i] = ASIZE - i;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < b -> size; i++ ) b -> data[i] = BSIZE - i;

    c = merge(a,b,1);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < c -> size; i++ ) printf("[%zu] %d\n", i, c -> data[i]);
    
    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);   
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5EcPEcjh1